# c++ find a key match in a bi-dimensional map (map of map)

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have the following map that I use to store customer names and a dictionary of itens selected with its code and description, like:

```
Name         Item Code, Item Description
Customer1 -> 1234,      Item 1
             1233,      Item 2
             1232,      Item 3
```

So I´m using the following structure:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> purchase_list;
```

Now I need to find for existing names and existing item codes.

To find existing names:

```
if (purchase_list.find(purchase_list.begin(), purchase_list.end(), "SearchName") != purchase_list.end())
   std::cout << "SeachName found!!" << std::endl;
```

For me this is supposed to work, but I´m getting the following error on compilation:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::find(std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator, std::string&)’ search_name) == purchase_list.end())
```

Shall I change the `"SearchName"` format ? What would be the correct syntax here ?

To search for item code I would repeat the same code looking for the found entry for the customer...

Thanks for helping...

Comment: What about using a `std::map`?

Comment: This is not how a `vector` works, you need to look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Sorry, it´s not a vector - it´s a map indeed. I had to copy from linux terminal to my notebook and chaged it completely... Too much hours coding...

Comment: Did you maybe mean`... != purchase_list.end()`?  It would help to see the complete error message.

Comment: @Mendez _"but I´m getting "no matching function for call to ' error on compilation..."_ At least post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) dude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find for std::map only takes a key value. So you would call it like this:

```
if (purchase_list.find("SearchName") != purchase_list.end())
     std::cout << "SearchName found!!" << std::endl;
```